# recursion cannot concatenate 'int' and 'NoneType' - how to change 'NoneType' to 'int'?

Tags: python, list, recursion, concatenation, nonetype

I'm trying to sort a binary list, which should work like this:

```
>>> blsort([1, 0, 1]) 
[0, 1, 1]
```

So I made this code:

```
def blsort(L):
if L == []:
    return []
elif L[0] == 0:
    L.insert(0, 0)
else:
    L.append(1)
    return L[0] + blsort(L[1:])
```

But I only get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

So somehow this code returns a `NoneType`, which I cannot concatenate with the `int` to a `list`.

I assume that `blsort(L[1:])` is of type `NoneType`. What can I do to make it of type `int`, so I can concatenate it with the other `int` to a `list`?

Comment: You are not returning anything here after second if condition `L.insert(0, 0)`

Comment: Why aren't you using `list.sort()` ?

Comment: I couldn't use list.sort(), it's an assignment for school and the point is learn recursion, so list.sort() was not allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning anything after second `if` condition :

```
elif L[0] == 0:
    L.insert(0, 0)
```

So when this statement is executed the return of `blsort` is `None` which leads to the error.

```
return L[0] + blsort(L[1:])
```

Comment: Also, the terminating condition would cause a `TypeError`.

Comment: yeah and I am also not sure about the whole program at all.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answers, that was indeed part of the solution. The second part for the solution was writing [0] (so '0' as a list item) instead of L[0].

This code here fixed it:

```
def blsort(L):
if len(L) == 0:
    return []
elif L[0] == 0:
    return [0] + blsort(L[1:])
else:
    return blsort(L[1:]) + [1]
```